# I am using the Foursquare API and keep getting an error where it does not have a zip/postal code and no results are returned

Tags: python

My code is this...

```
results = requests.get(url).json()['response']['groups'][0]['items']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-225-110fa1855079> in <module>
      1 london_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=df2['Postcode'],
      2                                    latitudes=df2['Latitude'],
----> 3                                    longitudes=df2['Longitude']
      4                                   )

<ipython-input-223-c23495b2f972> in getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius)
     16 
     17         # make the GET request
---> 18         results = requests.get(url).json()['response']['groups'][0]['items']
     19 
     20         # return only relevant information for each nearby venue

KeyError: 'groups'
```

I think it is because there is no data returned in some cases - is there a way I can just return no data?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in some cases you do not have group, you can simply change your line to:

```
results = requests.get(url).json()['response'].get('groups',[{}])[0].get('items', [])
```

it will returns `None` if you miss groups or items in your response.

Comment: Hello - thanks for this - I gave it a try and now it says:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I appreciate any further help. Thanks again

Comment: In which line?can you post sample of your response?

Comment: Hello again
I have posted the full code and the error here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426657/foursquare-api-no-results-returned

Thanks again.

Alasdair

Comment: Thanks so much - hugely appreciate it,

Comment: You're welcome, please consider checking the gray check and turn it to green.